# Filter rows by specific interval

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following DateTime values in a table, I need to filter the set only if there was a gap between this value > 5 seconds. This should be for a specific date, starting with the first row.

Any idea how to do it only in SQL using SQL Server 2012?

```
1     2014-04-02 05:33:56.60
2     2014-04-02 05:40:01.55
3     2014-04-02 05:52:45.81
4     2014-04-02 05:52:47.50
5     2014-04-02 06:35:48.84
6     2014-04-02 06:50:49.72
7     2014-04-02 07:01:02.71
8     2014-04-02 07:01:04.35
9     2014-04-02 07:01:09.29
10    2014-04-02 07:44:05.71
11    2014-04-02 08:37:47.06
```

Comment: What is your sql version?

Comment: I am using MS SQL 2012

Comment: If the numbers in the first column are dense (no gaps) then a simple self-join (pseudocode) `on a.id=b.id+1 and diff(a.timestamp,b.timestamp) > 5 sec`. Otherwise you need a correlated subquery using timestamps.

Comment: You could use the `LAG` or `LEAD` functions for this too I think. @JimGarrison Performance-wise, would it be a good idea to use analytical functions for this purpose?

Comment: No Idea for MSSQL. I use Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012 you can use lead function, Try following

```
;with cte as
(
    select id, d,  datediff(s, d, lead(d) over(order by d)) as diff from Test
)
select * from cte where diff > 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lead function to get the next date and datediff to calculate the seconds difference, then filter for your criteria.

```
with cte as
(
    select id, date, diff = datediff(s, date, lead(date) over(order by date)
    from tbl
)
select * from cte where diff > 5
```

Comment: using your code I get: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'. Could you please double check it?

Answer (score 1):

you can use it like this

```
WITH    rows AS
    (
    SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY InputDate) AS rn
    FROM    given_table
    )
SELECT  DATEDIFF(second, mc.InputDate, mp.InputDate)
FROM    rows mc
JOIN    rows mp
ON      mc.rn = mp.rn - 1
where DATEDIFF(second, mc.InputDate, mp.InputDate)> 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will also help you.

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE (ID INT,DT DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @TAB VALUES
(1 ,'2014-04-02 05:33:56.60'),
(2 ,'2014-04-02 05:40:01.55'),
(3 ,'2014-04-02 05:52:45.81'),
(4 ,'2014-04-02 05:52:47.50'),
(5 ,'2014-04-02 06:35:48.84'),
(6 ,'2014-04-02 06:50:49.72'),
(7 ,'2014-04-02 07:01:02.71'),
(8 ,'2014-04-02 07:01:04.35'),
(9 ,'2014-04-02 07:01:09.29'),
(10,'2014-04-02 07:44:05.71'),
(11,'2014-04-02 08:37:47.06')
```

--Query

```
SELECT  A.*,B.* 
FROM    @TAB A,@TAB B 
WHERE   A.ID = B.ID - 1
AND     DATEDIFF(SECOND,A.DT,B.DT) > 5
```

--Result

[image]